# Как проверить тип импортируемого файла используя Laravel+React?

Tags: javascript, php, база-данных, laravel, reactjs

Использую React+Laravel. Для импорта файла использую библиотеку Maatwebsite. Я только обучаюсь, поэтому все это для "домашнего проекта" :)
Имеется некая форма с инпутом для выбора файла и кнопка:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onChange={e => preUploadFile(e)} />
  <Button onClick={importFileHandler} disabled={!file}>Импорт</Button>
</form>
```

Выбранный файл я сохраняю в стейт:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
const preUploadFile = e => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        setFile(file);
};
```

Далее я его прокидываю в fetch:

```
// post for import
export const importFileInDataBase = async file => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        await fetch(`${url}/v2/organizations/import`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            console.log("result", response);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

После я вызываю эту функцию по клику на кнопку и так же по клику вызываю функцию, которая гет запросом запросит данные из таблицы и рендерит на странице.

```
const importFileHandler = () => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(importFileInDataBase(file));
    }).then(() => {
        getAllOrganizations();
    });
};
```

На бэке имеется Модель:

```
class ScheduledInspectionModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'scheduled_inspection'; // название таблицы
    protected $fillable = ['name_smp', 'name_control', "verification_start", "verification_end", 'verification_duration'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Контроллер:

```
class OrganizationsImportController extends Controller
{
    public function import(Request $request)
    {
        // return dd($request->file);
        Excel::import(new OrganizationsImport, $request->file);
        return response()->json('Импорт завершен');
    }
}
```

Ну и файл с настройками для импорта:

```
class OrganizationsImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new ScheduledInspectionModel([
            'name_smp' => $row[0],
            'name_control' => $row[1],
            'verification_start' => $row[2],
            'verification_end' => $row[3],
            'verification_duration' => $row[4],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно\нужно проверить тип импортируемого файла(необходим только файл типа xls)? Я так понимаю, саму проверку нужно сделать в контроллере?
PS: еще такой вопрос, хотелось бы вывести какое-то сообщение об успешном импорте либо нет. Я в контроллере возвращаю сообщение `response()->json('Импорт завершен');` как мне с этим можно раскрутиться ? )
PSS: может это как-то пригодится `dd($response)`:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#282
  -test: false
  -originalName: "test.xls"
  -mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpzFcBzS"
  basename: "phpzFcBzS"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpzFcBzS"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpzFcBzS"
  aTime: 2020-08-25 14:39:02
  mTime: 2020-08-25 14:39:02
  cTime: 2020-08-25 14:39:02
  inode: 318670
  size: 6144
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тип файла проверяется по [mime-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types). Можешь в рамках "домашнего проекта" проверить обычным if'ом вызвав метод `$request->file->getMimeType()`. Или использовать [валидацию](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation) по mime-type. Но еще лучше валидировать в классе **FormRequest**.
Ошибки валидации можно красиво обыгрывать в промисах (они приходят в статусе 422).

```
.then(response => {
    console.log("result", response);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response) // Смотри тут структуру
});
```

Если в контроллере возвращать массив, то он преобразуется в json response со статусом 200. Так можешь просто писать

```
return [
   'result' => 'success',
   'message' => 'Импорт завершен.',
];
```

В крайнем случае в fetch просто пропиши заголовки

```
headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
```

P.S. Советую сразу начать с прочтения этого https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md